# How can I apply my group policies on top of Microsoft security baselines?

Tags: security, windows-11, group-policy

I took a clean fresh VM, applied my group policies on it, backed up the `C:\Windows\System32\GroupPolicy` folder. now I want to apply it to a different VM where I've already applied the Windows 11 22H2 security baselines, in a way that my policies will replace those that were set by security baselines (if any).

obviously I can't just replace that folder with my own because that'd destroy the security baseline settings. I think I need a way to either merge them with my GPO taking priority for replacement or apply it on top of the currently set policies.

how can I do this?

p.s this is for personal use, no AD/AAD is included.

Comment: Wouldn’t the VM also have the security baseline’s applied to it, so you would only be, replacing it with the same thing plus the additional changes you made?

Comment: Simplest way would be to install RSAT (Install-WindowsFeature -Name GPMC), then comparing the two reports, in order to determine which policies are different. Configuring GPOs is a manual process since you don’t have an AD domain server which would still require manual configuration unless you imported a pre-configured configuration

Comment: I've captured my own settings in a separate GPO because they are static most of the time but Security baselines are updated with each Windows release. isn't there any other way than installing RSAT? AFAIK they're being deprecated in favor of WAC and also the process will still be a manual time consuming one. is there a way to use the same PowerShell script included in the baseline to apply my own GPO on top of security baselines?

Comment: How exactly are you applying your policies? It sounds like you should just run `lgpo` again for your own policies after the baseline local install script is done. `lgpo` only applies the actual settings from whatever gpo backup it's pointed at, so it won't overwrite everything

Comment: @Cpt.Whale I'm at the beginning phase, for now I have a VM with security baselines applied using the PowerShell script supplied with the baselines, on another VM I've changed group policies with local group policy editor GUI and then backed up the `C:\Windows\System32\GroupPolicy` folder. not sure what to do next. but wow is that possible? I will try it right away, that'd be awesome

Comment: WAC only supplements RSAT it doesn’t replace it.

Comment: @Cpt.Whale Thank you so much, just finished fully testing it and that's exactly what I was looking for. I saw it was included in the baseline and thought it's only used with the supplied PowerShell script and wouldn't have parameters or usages as a standalone executable. do you like to post it as answer? and thanks Ramhound

Comment: glad to hear it works for you, cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you should just run `lgpo` for your own policies after the baseline local install script is done.

`lgpo` only applies the actual settings from whatever gpo backup it's pointed at, so it won't overwrite everything from the baselines.

[lgpo.exe (or Local Group Policy Object) utility commands](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-security-baselines/lgpo-exe-local-group-policy-object-utility-v1-0/ba-p/701045)

[Download lgpo.exe](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=55319)